# @ConditionalOnExpression with #{systemEnvironment}

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to setup a `@ConditionalExpression` with the use of environment variables as follows:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{systemEnvironment['PUBLIC']?:'false'} != true")
```

I can see this is evaluated within following code:

```java
    private Boolean evaluateExpression(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, String expression) {
        BeanExpressionResolver resolver = beanFactory.getBeanExpressionResolver();
        if (resolver == null) {
            resolver = new StandardBeanExpressionResolver();
        }
        BeanExpressionContext expressionContext = new BeanExpressionContext(beanFactory, null);
        Object result = resolver.evaluate(expression, expressionContext);
        return (result != null && (boolean) result);
    }
```

The problem is that the `resolver.evaluate(expression, expressionContext);` returns `false != true` where this should already be a `boolean`:

```java
return (result != null && (boolean) result);
```

So this always fails with `ClassCastException`.

I tried also to fiddle with different kind of quoting and wrapping it whole with `${…}`, but always with the same result.

Question is: What is wrong with my conditional expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be this expression:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{!(systemEnvironment['PUBLIC']?:'false').equals('true')}")
```

---

Need to add that if this question is not for investigation purpose but for finding the way to improve your real (production-like) code, I'd really recommend you to:

1. always try to simplify that kind of expression because it really hard to understand what's really happening when you see a lot of boolean comparisons, default values, etc;
2. use spring-boot specific things more:

   1. when you're working with boolean expressions, you can usually replace `@ConditionalOnExpression` with `@ConditionalOnProperty` (optionally with `matchIfMissing` parameter);
   2. when you need to read environment variables, you can use [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding-from-environment-variables) feature instead of using things from (mostly) the pre-Spring-Boot era like `systemProperties`/`systemEnvironment`.